# Using useEffect dispatching when unmount

Tags: reactjs

I want to dispatch when the component unmount. My dispatch:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      add({
        ...values,
      });
  }, [var]);
  
const add = payload => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_S', payload })
      return dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_S' })
 }
 
 //now i unmount
 
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      add({}); //when unmount i want to send an emty data
    }
  }, []);
```

I my case, when i unmount the component, i want to send `add({});`- empty object, but anyway it doesn't work? why?

Comment: The code looks like it should work. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @technophyle  When i leave the page, i expect to send `add({})`, but  anyway when i access again the page, the last value from `dispatch({ type: 'ADD_S', payload })` again appears.

Comment: Ok, but are you sure the cleanup call is not being called? Try `console.log` in `ADD_S` reducer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The cleanup is being called, but not the dispatch anymore, or it never gets to the reducer after unmount. Have you been able to find some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Two facts need to be pointed out.

- When you return a function in `useEffect`, this function will fire when this component update **next time**. To know more, check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) out (Section: Effects with Cleanup)
- If you add an empty array in the `useEffect` dependency, the effect will only run once(did you do this intentionally?)

Since the second effect trigger only once, it may not be what you expect.